# Create view with multiple rows for one source row

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

I have a table which has an `offset` and a `qty` column.
I now want to create a view from that which has an entry for each precise `position`.

### **Table:**

```
offset |   qty   |  more_data
-------+---------+-------------
 1     |    3    | 'qwer'
 2     |    2    | 'asdf'
```

### **View:**

```
position | more_data
---------+------------
   1     | 'quer'
   2     | 'quer'
   3     | 'quer'
   2     | 'asdf'
   3     | 'asdf'
```

Is that even possible?

I would need to do that for Oracle (8! - 11), MS SQL (2005-) and PostgreSQL (8-)

Comment: Is offset the first value? Does the second one have to be the first value + 1? Does the last one have to be the first value + qty - 1?

Comment: It gonna be difficult to find an answer for all of those DBMS at once!

Comment: I edited the examples to clarify what I need: offset should be the first position and offset+qty-1 the last.

Answer (score 1):

Based on you input/output:

```
with t(offset, qty) as (
  select 1, 3 from dual
)
select offset + level - 1 position
  from t
connect by rownum <= qty

POSITION
--------
       1
       2
       3
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, to answer the specific question (i.e. a table with just the one row):

```
select rn posn from (
    select offset-1+rownum rn from the_table 
    connect by level between offset and qty 
);
```

In reality, your table will have multiple rows, so you will need to restrict the inner query to 1 object row, otherwise I think you will get huge, incorrect output. If you can provide more details about the table/data a more complete answer could be given.

Answer (score 1):

For Postgres:

```
select offst, generate_series(offst, qty) as position
from the_table
order by offst, num;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/e70d9/4

I don't have anything as ancient as 8.0, 8.1 or 8.2 around but it should work on those pre-historic versions as well.

Note that `offset` is a reserved word in Postgres. You should find a different name for that column